# Open my new page in pop up in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, popup

I have a regular page.When i clicked on a button it will be open in that page with some asp controls. what i need is that i want to open that page in a pop up page with close button inside it.I searched but i didn't find a properly cod for this. can any body help me?
thanks
[image]

Comment: You might want to look in to jQuery UI dialog, if I understand your question correctly. http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Comment: thank you for your replying.but in need some thing like the picture in my question.(I edited it) just open my next page though a button, in a new page with out any toolbar like that.

Comment: For this you can use the window open method http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

Comment: thank you, the problem of this cod is that it open a blank page and after clicking on my button the main page is also redirect to the next page. and i don't want it.

Comment: Look at the answer I posted. If you still don't manage to get it working, post the code you have, and I can help you fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function OpenPopup() {

       window.open("ProductClass.aspx", "List", "toolbar=no, location=no,status=yes,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=no, width=900,height=500,left=430,top=100");
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use windows.open in javascript.

```
    <html>
    <body>

    <script type="text/javascript">
function windowOpen() {
    myWindow=window.open('http://myurl.com','_blank','width=200,height=100, scrollbars=no,resizable=no')

    myWindow.focus()
}
    </script>
    <input type="button" value="Open Window" onclick="windowOpen()">
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: thank you but it gives me this error:

Error 4 'ASP.author_viewpublishedmenuscript_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'windowOpen' and no extension method 'windowOpen' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.author_viewpublishedmenuscript_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) F:\All Site Projects\Final Version Journal\IN USE Journal\Jornal\Author\ViewPublishedMenuScript.aspx 230

Comment: If this is an `asp:Button` then you need the `OnClientClick` property in order to trigger a client function and not the server-side function.

Answer (score 1):

Use return before your function

```
 <html>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function windowOpen() {
      myWindow=window.open('http://myurl.com','_blank','width=200,height=100, scrollbars=no,resizable=no')
      myWindow.focus()
      return false;
  }
</script>
<asp:button id="btnClick" text="Open Window" onClientClick="return windowOpen()">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the below code

ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "MessagePopUp", "window.location.href = 'Home.aspx';", true);

Answer (score 0):

hi all Kindly use the below code

```
function ShowPopup() {
        $("#panOne").dialog({
            autoOpen: true,
            appendTo: "form",
            height: 600,
            width: 900
        });
    }
```

**appendTo**: `"form"` is Important as if you are not using it will `autopostback` all values